# C++: string = NULL gives SEGFAULT 11?

Tags: c++

I modified my project today to allow it save files in different folders, and I found my program crashed when startup:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Because I introduced so many changes before testing my program, I started comment out all the functions I added, but no help. I even put

```
cout << "hello world" << endl;
return 0;
```

as the first two lines in `int main()`, it still crashed without showing anything.

Finally, it took me one hour to figure out the error. The modification includes declaring a global variable

```
string foldername = NULL;
```

The line above seems innocence, it just declaring a global variable.

Then I tried a simple program:

```
#include <string>

std::string a = NULL;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

and it also crashed at startup.

Why declaring a string global variable as NULL make the program silently crashed without any info?

Comment: You assign integer zero to a `std::string`. Why you expect something other than a crash? Either use pointers or have some string-null, like `""`.

Comment: The default constructor of `std::string` creates an empty string, you don't need to initialize it to be empty.

Comment: How can you check for string str = 0?  Check if string is null doesn't work:
"if (!str)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `std::string` - as opposite to inherited from C `char*` strings - always holds a valid string. It may be empty, but it cannot be NULL. If you try to initialise `std::string` with NULL it will try blindly to copy C-like string from NULL address, which is undefined behaviour.

Just use

```
std::string a;
```

and then `a` will be initialised empty string.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is assigned only to pointer types and that too in C. The C++ way is `std::nullptr_t` or `nullptr`. Either declare pointer to a string like

```
std::string * a = nullptr;
```

or leave it to the string constructor

```
std::string a = "";    // equivalent to std::string a;
```